# Is Node.js a programming language?

Tags: discussion, blog

So, I noticed [the recent blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/2013-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/) about the survey:

[image]

I don't understand why Node.js is in the programming languages list. Can anyone elaborate?

Comment: Very good question because it actually isn't a language.

Comment: Cpt. Obvious to the rescue.

Comment: To be fair, PHP isn't a programming language either. *ducks*

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think it's just the header in the chart that is incorrect.

If you look at the [data source](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tiautbb955sa9ql/2013%20Stack%20Overflow%20Survey%20Responses.xlsx), you'll see that the question was this:

> Which of the following languages or technologies have you used significantly in the past year?